# Kafka Connect to access two sinks (ftp and sql)

Tags: apache-kafka, ftp, apache-kafka-connect

I need to send files data to an ftp server using kafka connect sink, after an entire file is received by the server, I also have to sen an acknowledgment to change the status of those tasks in the db.

I would like to know what's the best way to go here, I initially thought about creating a custom ftp kafka connect which will also change the task db status. 
Is it the best way to go, or are there other options here?

Answer (score 0):

What's the requirement driving the need to update the status in the task database?

Off the top of my head, you could write a custom application that tracks the offset of the FTP sink vs available messages, and updates a database as needed.

Worth noting is that https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/ can track the delivery of messages in a Kafka Connect pipeline, and alert on latencies.